# Self drilling dyrwall anchor cannot go all the way into the hole

Tags: drywall-anchor

I bought this self drilling dyrwall anchor https://www.lowes.com/pd/E-Z-Ancor-50-Pack-1-5-8-in-x-1-2-in-Dia-Standard-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/1098803
Our curtain is very long and we wanted to place the bracket 2 inches from the ceiling. I first tried the hole at the top but it was stuck in the middle. Then I used the drill bit and it couldn't penetrate either. Not sure what is behind it and doesn't feel like a stud. Next I used the drill bit on the two holes below and they were penetrated easily. However, the anchors still couldn't go all the way in as shown in the picture. Now I have patched the holes. The only thing I can think of is the root of anchors being too wide and it's where they got stuck. But in the youtube videos, they went in pretty easily. Does anyone know how to deal with this issue?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you hammer a nail in the hole where the anchor hit refusal?

Comment: I didn't try a nail but drill bit went in pretty easily

Comment: but did the drill bit hit anything behind the drywall?

Comment: For the top one yes, but not for the lower two

Comment: Double top plate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These anchors are great for drywall mounted on 2" studs but if drywall is mounted on furring strips, the 1-5/8" anchors will be too long. Once your hole is self drilled, remove the anchor and cut off the drilling, flat, part. You do need to screw them in with a fair amount of torque.

Comment: But my drill bit went all the way in and it's longer than the anchor. It's very strange

Comment: Using shorter anchors sounds reasonable. Do you know if I can reuse the patched holes?

Comment: I'd try the old holes. They make the same type of drywall anchor but out of metal. they can be torqued higher than those plastic ones.

Comment: Will the patched holes be as stable as before? I'm worried it might fall off

Comment: It would depend on how much you might have enlarged them with the anchors.  If in doubt, try new holes.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you’re trying to set those into the wooden top plate of your wall.

If you had any wood shavings while drilling, just use a long (>3”) wood screw.

Those anchors are fine, but are for hollow plaster walls. If you are truly in empty space on the lower holes, you might just need to push harder to engage the threads while spinning it in.

Comment: For the lower holes, I was pushing hard enough that the anchor head even has worn out. I also used the stud finder, and none of these two holes was detected

Comment: Stud detectors aren't perfect, @James.